# how to remove notification icon from salesforce1 navigation bar?

Tags: notifications, salesforce

I  want to customize the top bar of salesforce1 app.
I wish to remove the notification icon and put a title in the bar instead.

I have tried branding it ..but it seems to provide options only for changing color and putting a splash etc.

Can anybody guide me on how to make the above mentioned changes.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Esha